# ¿Cómo se dice "no se acumulan" en inglés? ¿Es correcto decir "are not accumulated"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos

Quiero traducir esta frase al inglés:

> Los permisos **no se acumulan** durante la configuración.

Y de momento lo traduje así:

> The permissions **are not accumulated** during the configuration

Sin embargo, no sé si lo que estoy diciendo con esta frase es, por contra:

> Los permisos **no están acumulados** durante la configuración.

Mi pregunta es: ¿"They are not accumulated" sirve tanto para decir "no se acumulan" como "no están acumulados"?

Comment: "The permissions are not accumulated" is a passive voice as "Los permisos no se acumulan" (pasiva refleja). If you want to keep the meaning you could say too : "Los permisos no son aumulados" (normal passive though it is more normal the previous one).

Comment: Son dos cosas diferentes, el comentario de Juanillo te acerca al problema real que es el uso del reflexivo. ¿Se acumulan a si mismos?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because está pidiendo ayuda sobre el inglés, no sobre el castellano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Qué tal esto?:

> Permissions do not accumulate during configuration.

O podría ser también (no tan literal):

> Permissions are not stacked during configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences are different, but the difference is very subtle.

Using `estar` in this case would refer to the state of the permissions during the configuration (in other words, more of a description), and using the reflexive verb would indicate the action of accumulation.

It seems to me that in this particular case, `no se acumulan` would be a more precise utterance, though using `estar` wouldn't seem unnatural to anyone. (It would simply cause a slightly, and largely ignorable, difference in interpretation.)

Answer (score 0):

Es válido decir ***permissions are not accumulated*** para ***no se acumulan los permisos***, aunque en realidad el significado de esto en Español sería tal como ***los permisos no son acumulados***, si se viese la traducción palabra por palabra.

En expresar que ***no se acumulan los permisos*** en la configuración, en Inglés esto se expresaría como ***permissions do not accumulate***.